# Avoiding multiple checkbox forms for has_and_belongs_to_many with nested attributes - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, partial, nested-attributes, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm new to rails and getting stuck on best practice for complex forms.

I have 3 layers deep nested attribute forms. User > Recipient > Gift_profile.

I want to create a single partial for _gift_profile_fields so I can use the fields in multiple forms around the site and not repeat myself. They are located at different levels of the hierarchy.

It works fine until I add the check_box_tag where I manually specify the name for a HABTM relationship with another model called Sport, which has_and_belongs_to_many gift profiles.

```
<%= f.label :gender, "Gender" %>
<%= f.select :gender, options_for_select(GiftProfile::GENDERS), :include_blank => true %>

<% for sport in Sport.find(:all) %>
<div>
 <%= check_box_tag "recipient[gift_profile_attributes][sport_ids][]", sport.id, @gift_profile.sports.include?(sport) %>
 <%= sport.sport %>
</div>
```

The form works perfectly, but obviously only works on the recipient form. It fails to work on other form locations where I assume I would need:

```
"user[recipient_attributes][gift_profile_attributes][sport_ids][]"
```

Is there a helper or way to dynamically update this so that I can continue to use the partial on all my forms? Is check_box_tag the best way to do this or is there another rails helper?

A friend suggested I use a helper to generate the name depending on the controller.